# Parallel Algorithm for calculating the maximum difference

Tags: c++, c++11, tbb

I am currently implementing an parallel algorithm for calculating the maximum difference between two elements such that the smaller number appears before the larger number. I am using the **parallel_invoke** from the tbb library to achieve this. My implementation is as following

```
int calculateMaxDiff(int *src, int start, int end){
    int maxVal = -1;
    int maxRight = src[end -1];

    for(int i = end - 2; i >= start; i--){
        if(src[i] > maxRight){
            maxRight = src[i];
        }else{
            int diff = maxRight - src[i];
            if(diff > maxVal){
                maxVal = diff;
            }
        }
    }


    return maxVal;
};

int compute_max_diff(int *src, int size)
{
    int half1_diff;
    int half2_diff;

    parallel_invoke([&]{ half1_diff = calculateMaxDiff(src, 0, size/2);},
                    [&]{ half2_diff = calculateMaxDiff(src, size/2, size);});


    int maxDiff = half1_diff + half2_diff;

    return maxDiff;
}
```

Now for the above code segment i am using the following as the sample array

```
int src[] = {12, 9, 18, 3, 7, 11, 6, 15, 6, 1, 10};
int size = 11;
```

For the above sample the output or maximum difference needs to be 12 but i seem to be getting 18. I ran the algorithm sequentially and got the expected result. But once i introduce **parallel_invoke** i can't seem to be getting the right result.

Comment: that seems like an inefficient use of parallelism

Comment: it is but i have a restriction to use parallel_invoke, what i am stumped about is why is the output off?

Comment: Before running parallel, try the two-halves algorithm serially, i.e. erase the parallel_invoke/lambda boilerplate and just make two sequential calls to calculateMaxDiff.  What do you get?  Also, after you've debugged that, you might consider how your algorithm would handle this four-element input: {0, 0, 100, 100}.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting 18 as a sum of 9 from the first half (which is 18-9) and 9 from the second half which is (15-6). When you run sequentially I do assume you call `calculateMaxDif(src, 0, size)` which would work well because it goes through all elements of the array. However when you call 2 functions in halves - it doesn't reach the needed pair (3, 15) because 3 is in the first half, and 15 is in another.

Comment: you are right each sub problem will have a different pairing and different max diff, so would say i need to modify the logic in order to get the pair (3,15).

Comment: well, if you have a strict requirement for 2 processes you may store min value from first half, max value from right half, and check 3 values - max diff from left, max diff from right and diff between max right and min left

Comment: so you are saying i need to get the maximum value from right side and minimum value from the left. But what exactly does this do right here

Comment: I said you need to find a maxDiff from the left, then max Diff from the right, AND also compare min left max right, because you might have 3 scenarios: 1) your pair is located in left 2) your pair is located in right 3) your pair is split between. You got case 1 and 2 covered, but for case 3 you just get min value from left, max value from right, then take difference and compare. Because every element from the left half comes before every element from right by definition, so in this case you'll get min from left 3, and max from right 15

Comment: your are right the calculateMaxDiff function gets the maximum diff for left and right sides, but where i am confused is getting the min value from left and max right, would this require another function to get these values.

Comment: It suffices to have a single function that returns a triple: min, max, and maximum diff.